# Can the aws cli list the available commands without descriptions for a given service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Using the aws cli, is there a way to list the available commands for a given service without showing the descriptions?  For example, the following command will display more information than just the available commands

```
aws codecommit help
```

As shown in the image below the result of the command above has a long list of descriptions before showing the actual commands.

[image: code commit help output snippet]

I would like to be able to see the commands only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [aws-shell](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-shell), an integrated shell for working with the AWS CLI. It extends the CLI with many features, like displaying available commands and auto-completion.